# Solving equations of motion of holomorphic BF theory - pure gauge in complex coordinates

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, connections, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0412014) paper by Bailieu and Tanzini, aspects of holomorphic BF theory are presented.

Holomorphic BF theory on a four dimensional Kahler manifold is discussed from page 5, and on page 8 the following equations of motion are derived from it:

$$
F_{\bar{m}\bar{n}}=0,~~~~~\epsilon^{mn\bar{m}\bar{n}}D_{\bar{n}}B_{mn}=0.
$$

The authors claim that these equations imply that classically, $A_m$ is undetermined, $A_{\bar{m}}$ is pure gauge, and $B_{mn}$ is holomorphic.

My question is, **why is $A_{\bar{m}}$ definitely pure gauge?**

Now, the pure gauge configuration $A_{\bar{m}}=-\partial_{\bar{m}}gg^{-1}$ certainly appears to be a solution of $F_{\bar{m}\bar{n}}=0$.

However, in general, flat connections can only be written as pure gauge in **simply-connected** regions of the underlying manifold. (This is because to gauge transform a connection, $A$, to zero, the group element, $U$, required is the parallel transport of $A$ along a curve, and to show that $U$ does not depend on the curve, the manifold must be simply-connected. Further details can be found in the answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98484/field-strength-vanishes-iff-a-mu-is-pure-gauge) question.)

The authors do not seem to be assuming that the Kahler manifold at hand is simply-connected.

Therefore, why is $A_{\bar{m}}$ pure gauge? Does this follow somehow because they use complex coordinates?

Comment: Cross-post at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/533613/solving-equations-of-motion-of-holomorphic-bf-theory-pure-gauge-in-complex-coo